# adding eventlistener for multiple forms on chat bubbles

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a chatbot, for each chat message bubble, I have a feedback form and the response, see below

```
function appendMessage(name, img, side, text, date) {
      //   Simple solution for small apps
      console.log(name)
      if (name === "    Aurora"){
      
      const msgHTML = `
<div class="msg ${side}-msg">
  <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${img})"></div>

    
    <form autocomplete="off" class="feedback-inputarea" id="feedbackForm">
    <input type="text" id="correct-text" class="correct-text" placeholder="enter your feedback">
    <button type="submit" onclick="checkFeedback();" id="send-correct" name="send-correct" class="send-correct" value="Submit">Submit</button><br>
    </form>  
    

  <div class="msg-bubble">
    
    <div class="msg-info">
      <div class="msg-info-name">${name}</div>
      <div class="msg-info-time">${date}</div>
    
    </div>

    <div class="msg-text">${text}</div>  

  </div>
 
  
</div>
`;
    //insert list of elements into the response
      msgerChat.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", msgHTML);
      msgerChat.scrollTop += 500;

}
```

The problem is the eventListener function for feedback form only works for feedback form on the first reply bubble. I assume the form object contains a list of forms so I need to loop through each one of them to get the input content, but it still doesn't work, see below

```
function checkFeedback(){

  
  if (correctionForm !== null) {
    

    correctionForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {

      console.log('this is event classname' + event.target.className)

      //correctionForm should be a list of forms, find each form 
      
      if (event.target.className === 'feedback-inputarea'){

        var feedback_content = get(".feedback-inputarea")[0].value

    
        sessionStorage.setItem("feedback_content",JSON.stringify(feedback_content)); 

    
         
  }}

        );
      }}
```